# When correct session name and pin is entered, the response is 'null'

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database (with Angular 9) and I need to set some rules to access this data only if the user has the pin code. Also, if he has the pin code he can change it.

Here is my database:

```
sessions
  session_one
    some_data: 'can',
    some_data_2: 'you',
    old_pin: 1234,
    pin: 1234
  session_two
    some_data: 'help',
    some_data_2: 'me',
    old_pin: -1,
    pin: -1
  session_three
    some_data: 'please?',
    some_data_2: 'thanks',
    old_pin: 5555,
    pin: 5555
```

And my rules:

```
 {
   "rules": {
     "sessions": {
       "$session": {
         ".indexOn": "pin",
         ".read": "query.orderByChild === 'pin' &&
                   query.equalTo === data.child('pin').val()",
         ".validate": "!data.exists() ||
                   newData.child('old_pin').val() === data.child('pin').val()"

       }
     }
   }
 }
```

I did some research and I found that in Firebase Realtime Database you can't read a part of an element, the thing here is that I want to know if the element with that key exists let me read only if I have the pin code.

For example, I search for the session named 'session_three' if exist and I have the pin code I can read and modify the data, if exists and I don't have the pin code I can't read/write but I can know if exists because if it doesn't exist I could create a new session with that name.

Angular code:

```
this.db.database.ref("sessions/"+this.session).orderByChild('pin').equalTo(this.pin).once('value').then((snap) => {
  this.enterInSession(snap);
}).catch(() => {
  this.db.database.ref('sessions/' + this.inputSession).set({
      some_data: 'loren',
      some_data_2: 'ipsum',
      old_pin: -1
      pin: -1
    }).then(() => {
      this.enterInSession(this.inputSession);
    }).catch(() => {
      this.enterPinDialog();
    });
});
```

It works pretty well, the problem is that in 'snap', when I entered the correct session name and pin, the response is 'null' instead of the session data.

Thank you so much! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the rules on the level where the query runs. Since your query runs on `/sessions`, that's also where you need to define the `.read` rule. And that also immediately shows why this approach won't work: on `/sessions` the `data` would refer to the data for all sessions, and there's no `pin` property to check the value of.

I find it easiest to remember that Firebase enforces its security rules when you attach the listener, and it has no reasonable way to do that with your rules without reading each individual document, which wouldn't' scale.

---

The only information from the client that is passed into the security rules is:

1. The [auth token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#auth) for the active user.
2. The path of the data that is being read/written.
3. If the read is a query, the information from the query.

There is no way to pass other custom information into the security rules, so you will have to make sure the information is in one of the above.

My common solution to this is to encode any security information into the key of the node.

```
sessions
  session_one_1234
    some_data: 'can',
    some_data_2: 'you',
    old_pin: 1234,
    pin: 1234
  session_two_-1
    some_data: 'help',
    some_data_2: 'me',
    old_pin: -1,
    pin: -1
  session_three_5555
    some_data: 'please?',
    some_data_2: 'thanks',
    old_pin: 5555,
    pin: 5555
```

Now you need to know with the original key (like `session_one` **and** the PIN of the document to be able to construct its path, which is what's necessary to read it.

The much simpler rules that go with this:

```
{
   "rules": {
     "sessions": {
       "$session": {
         ".read": true, // if you know the path, you can read it
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

As long as you don't grant the user permissions to read all of `/sessions` there's no chance of them finding out the keys of the session nodes.